# Is it "Greater-Than" or "Greater-or-Equal"?

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, mobile-web

In the mobile profile page, the rep target tracker shows *Next privilege **>**%d Rep*, which I believe should have been *Next privilege **>=**%d Rep*.

Is it right or wrong?

[image: A]

I think it's better replaced by this as it's clearer than `>=` or `≥`

```
Next privilege at %d Rep
               ^^
```

Comment: I think it is right, with exactly 3000 we already have the privilege. The only exception I experienced: in the combined reputation page, we will see our accounts only from 201, not from 200.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It's not **badge**-progress, but **reputation**-progress.

Comment: @iDebug privilege progress, but yeah it's based only on reputation. My bad. :)