# Showing up in network flair requires 201 rep instead of 200?

Tags: support, flair, network-profile

[A comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300264/is-it-greater-than-or-greater-or-equal#comment975807_300264) from *[peterh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259412/peterh)* suggests that

> in the combined reputation page *(and flair)*, we will see our accounts only from 201, not from 200

[image: A]

I then [edited this into the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/160292/revisions), but still not sure because I've never seen discussions or had personal experiences, so I'm looking for confirmation here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid peter was wrong.

[Here is a user with exactly 200 reputation points here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/130839/dave-gamble). As you can see that user got both the network profile reputation graph and global flair for MSE, which require 200 reputation.

1. [Reputation graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/45390/dave-gamble?tab=reputation):

   > [image]
2. [Combined flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/45390.png):

   > [image]

As seen [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/45390/dave-gamble?tab=accounts), the user got other accounts e.g. 111 rep on Super User.

Comment: And then I [removed that from FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/160292/revisions).

Comment: @iDebug thanks, next time better check the facts before editing a faq.

Comment: The [flair page says](/users/flair) "sites where you have *more than 200 reputation* will appear" so that should probably be changed

Comment: @Cai yup, to "sites where you have 200 reputation or more will appear"

Comment: @iDebug oops, [I might be responsible for the mistake](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231976/inconsistent-buggy-combined-flair-behavior-when-reputation-is-exactly-200#comment763560_231976). *blush*.